# How do I, in nodejs, set up a Mongo viewer (like Mongo-Express) on the same port as my main app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, port, appfog

I'm new to just about everything with regards to nodejs and Mongodb but I managed to get a simple app up and running and now I want a database viewer. I found Mongo-Express and installed it on my localhost where it works fine. The viewer is configured in a config file with host a baseUrl and port.

The problem is on the live server (AppFog) where I only have one port available which is occupied by my main app. How do I solve this issue? Can they run on the same port or is there another viewer available that doesn't need to run on a separate port?

Comment: i use mongohub to view my database directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend [MongoMate](http://mongomate.bensbit.co.uk/) which can either run as a standalone MongoDB Browser or (what you want) it can be mounted within an [Express](http://expressjs.com) app. See the webpage for more info.

PS. I built MongoMate :P

Comment: Thanks, just what I'm searching for!

Comment: @Ndesh No problem, if you have any issues feel free to drop us a note https://github.com/bencevans/mongomate/issues :)